Wondering if there is a way to auto format pasted text entered into a cell to 1) delete paragraph spaces, and 2 ) to limit characters per line
Wondering if there is a way to auto format pasted text entered into a cell in excel to 1) delete paragraph spaces, and 2) to limit characters per line via wrap after a certain number of characters. I typically try to self-service these things based on either formulas or vba found on helpful sites such as this, but I'm drawing a blank here. My task, essentially is copy/pasting emails in the a processing system, I created a template to highlight and auto-copy the text, but in order to format the email to fit within the system parameters I'm using notepad to manually format.
I'd like to format this
From emailaddress@emailaddress.com
CC: Jane.doe@emailaddress.com; john.alphabet@emailaddress.org
SUBJECT: please update file notes to including the following

Good Morning,

There are 5 permanent portals to the pool line and the request was only for 3, so we sent a request for repair of two and this should be completed anytime on any date, 2024. 

Thank you! 

As:
From emailaddress@emailaddress.com CC: Jane.doe@emailaddress.com; john.alphabet@emailaddress.org 
SUBJECT: please update file notes to including the following
Good Morning, There are 5 permanent 
portals to the pool line and the request 
was only for 3, so we sent a request for 
repair of two and this should be 
completed anytime on any date, 2024. 
Thank you!

I tried using a combination of the len, left, and right formulas, however this of course did nothing for the spacing and it didn't seem to fill down correctly.


Word is better suited for handling multiple paragraphs compared to Excel.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Find property (Word)


Range.Duplicate property (Word)


Range.MoveStart method (Word)


Range.Find property (Word)

Option Explicit

Sub FormatMultipleLines()
    Dim oTab As Table, rngBody As Range, aTxt, iLen As Long
    Dim sLine As String, sTxt As String, i As Long
    Const CHAR_WIDTH = 46 ' max chars in a line, modify as needed
    Set oTab = ActiveDocument.Tables(1) ' at least 2 cells 
    ' copy mail, skip below line if the mail is on clipboard
    oTab.Range.Cells(1).Range.Copy 
    ' paste into Word
    oTab.Range.Cells(2).Range.Paste
    With oTab.Range.Cells(2).Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        ' Remvoe blank paragraph
        .Text = "^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        ' Merge From and CC lines
        .Text = "^pCC"
        .Replacement.Text = " CC"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        ' Locate SUBJECT
        If .Execute(FindText:="SUBJECT") Then
            Set rngBody = .Parent.Duplicate
        End If
    End With
    If Not rngBody Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the range of mail body
        rngBody.End = oTab.Range.Cells(2).Range.End
        rngBody.MoveStart Word.wdParagraph, 1
        rngBody.MoveEnd Word.wdParagraph, -1
        rngBody.Select
        aTxt = Split(Replace(rngBody.Text, vbCr, " "))
        ' Reorganize mail body as multiple paragraphy
        For i = 0 To UBound(aTxt)
            If Len(sLine & " " & aTxt(i)) < CHAR_WIDTH Then
                sLine = sLine & " " & aTxt(i)
            Else
                If sTxt = "" Then
                    sTxt = sLine & " "
                Else
                    sTxt = sTxt & vbCr & sLine & " "
                End If
                sLine = aTxt(i)
            End If
        Next
        ' Update mail body
        rngBody.Text = Mid(sTxt, 2) & vbCr
    End If
End Sub



Thanks so much! I'll have to try this. It appears it'll definitely minimize the manual notepad reformatting

Okay, so for the more advanced stuff you'll need VBA.  However, at a basic level you can get away with a couple of LAMBDA functions.  (This is still somewhat rough-and-ready though, with lots of room for improvement)
As a first step, let's break things down into 3 rows of data: everything before the SUBJECT line, the SUBJECT line, and everything after the SUBJECT line:
=LET(z,TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE("",TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(10)),LAMBDA(x,y,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,x,IF(LEFT(y,8)="SUBJECT:",CHAR(10) & TRIM(y) & CHAR(10),TRIM(y))))),CHAR(10)),TRIM(INDEX(z,1)) & CHAR(10) & TRIM(INDEX(z,2)) & CHAR(10) & TRIM(INDEX(z,3)))

This will create 3 lines of data.  However, we want to wrap the third one (TRIM(INDEX(z,3))) at a specified number of characters.
So, the first thing to do is create a Named Range called REVERSE, with the following formula:
=LAMBDA(value,IF(value="","",REDUCE("",TEXTSPLIT("a" & REPT("|",LEN(value)-1),"|"),LAMBDA(out,r,MID(value,1+LEN(out),1) & out))))

All this does is take an input string, and reverse it: i.e. "Sample Text" → "txeT elpmaS"
This is needed for the second formula: create Named Range called WRAPTEXT, with this formula:
=LAMBDA(txt, lim, REDUCE("", TEXTSPLIT(txt, " ")," "),LAMBDA(str, val, TRIM(str & IF(FIND(CHAR(10), REVERSE(CHAR(10) & TRIM(str & " " & val)))<=(lim+1), " ", CHAR(10)) & val))))

This will take a text string, and a number of characters, and then wrap the text to the specified number of characters, breaking at spaces.  (n.b. this can have issues with things like single-words that are longer than the line length; you can create a far more comprehensive function using VBA)  You may notice that this uses the REVERSE function we created earlier, in order to count backwards and find the last linebreak.
Then, we can swap out TRIM(INDEX(z,3)) for WRAPTEXT(TRIM(INDEX(z,3)),40), and it will wrap the text on the third line (i.e. "everything after the SUBJECT line") at 40 characters:
=LET(z,TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE("",TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(10)),LAMBDA(x,y,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,x,IF(LEFT(y,8)="SUBJECT:",CHAR(10)&TRIM(y)&CHAR(10),TRIM(y))))),CHAR(10)),TRIM(INDEX(z,1)) & CHAR(10) & TRIM(INDEX(z,2)) & CHAR(10) & WRAPTEXT(TRIM(INDEX(z,3)),40))


Thanks so much! I think I'll try this one 1st, since it's formula based, I'm only working on this task for the next few weeks or so, so i don't know that I want to necessarily go the vba route if it'll be too involved.
